# C++ memory analysis

Tags: c++, memory

What are some of the good tools for analysing memory (for footprint, allocation and deallocation)? I am familiar with valgrind. If there are tools apart from that, would be nice to know about them.

Best.

Comment: What CPU/operating system(s) ?

Comment: What do you want to do that valgrind doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

IBM has [Rational Purify](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/purify/?S_TACT=105AGY59&S_CMP=09&ca=dtl-0903) for both Windows and Linux.  I haven't used it, as it's rather costly, but there is a free trial available.

Comment: I used it about a decade ago, and thought it very nice.

Comment: I used it also about a decade ago, until it was bought by IBM, no new versions were announced anymore, and it started to crash because my application became too big.  Since then, no more.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about valgrind I suppose that you are interested in Linux software.

You can easily build your custom report for footprint allocation and deallocation by using [MTrace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mtrace). It is not directly C++ but directly integrated into the GlibC. As far as I know C++ new and delete operators use this to allocate the memory before calling the constructor and deallocate memory after calling the destructor.

Answer (score 1):

The nice thing about mcheck is that you automatically have it whenever you use glibc. Set the environment variable MALLOC_CHECK_ to 1, and diagnostic is printed on stderr every time heap inconsistency is detected; if set to 2, abort() is called immediately.

The mcheck documentation is here:
http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Heap-Consistency-Checking.html

You can also use mtrace to trace malloc in endless detail:
http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Allocation-Debugging.html